# How do atmospheric concentrations of CO2 and NOx vary by city and within cities?

Tags: pollution, greenhouse-gas-emissions

What would a well ventilated port city such as Honolulu, Hawaii, USA have for the concentrations (in parts per million) of CO<sub>2</sub> or NO<sub>x</sub>, compared to a city like Linfen, China which is the site of a large coal industry?

By how much would concentration change between different regions in the same city? That is, what range of concentrations are we looking at when it comes to NO<sub>2</sub>, for example? Feel free to post information on other gasses such as O<sub>3</sub> and general pollutants.

Comment: While this is borderline OK on Chem (borderline because it's not really asking anything conceptual in chemistry terms), I'll migrate this to [sustainability.se] as it seems to be a better platform for this question.

Comment: Note to self or others answering: see Jacobson on urban dome effect for CO2

Comment: @EnergyNumbers, the small amount of research I've done seems to show that the most comprehensive (free) collection of data that addresses this question (at least the CO2 part) is found at co2science.org, run by the Drs Idso.  While they publish lots of conclusions about CO2 levels, and climate change, that I find bogus, it's not clear to me that the **data** on their site, most of which was collected by other scientists, is invalid, or has been massaged in any way.  But, I'm not in academia either.  Do you have an opinion on this?

Comment: @Nate IMO: Not a reliable source, and not a trustworthy conveyer of data; if it's referenced, then go to the original source. If it's not, then ignore it. So either way, no need to cite cranks.

Comment: http://acrobotic.com/smart-citizen might be worth watching, it's an attempt to get this data in an open-source way. Cheap compared to the alternatives, and the dataset should start being useful by the end of the year.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### CO<sub>2</sub>

Don't have time to fully address this now, but here's an interesting [plot of results from Boston, USA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIeNO.jpg):

[image: BU CO2 Plot]

As you can see from this graph, CO<sub>2</sub> levels can vary quite a bit over *time* simply within **one city**.

You can see a seasonal amplitude of +/- ~12 ppm that's due to plant photosynthesis speeding up (reducing CO<sub>2</sub>) in summer, and slowing down (allowing CO<sub>2</sub> to increase) in winter.

Based on this, you can imagine that areas with different levels of sun or vegetation would then also experience different *average* CO<sub>2</sub> levels as well.  From the previous web page:

> The CO2 concentration level in Boston is almost always several ppm
> higher than the global average, because cities, with their buildings
> and vehicles burning natural gas, gasoline, and oil, are relatively
> large sources of CO2.  For example, in May 2011 the monthly average
> CO2 level at Mauna Loa was 394 ppm; at BU (Boston University), it was
> 405.

- [Here is a source with a collection of CO2 data from several different weather stations](http://scrippsco2.ucsd.edu/data/atmospheric_co2.html), including a couple in Hawaii.
- If you want a visual plot, the US Nat'l Oceanic & Atmospheric Association publishes an online tool that displays CO<sub>2</sub> concentration in the **free troposphere** [here](https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/ccgg/carbontracker/co2weather.php):

[image: NOAA CarbonTracker]

Because it's displaying CO<sub>2</sub> 1 to 5 km above the ground, it's going to smooth out the variations due to local forests, or power plants.   But, you certainly can see areas of high CO<sub>2</sub> concentration over eastern Europe / Black Sea (downwind from central Europe) and also China / Korea / Japan (downwind from China's industrial hubs).

### NOx

The US Environmental Protection Agency has a [report on NOx here](http://www.epa.gov/ttn/catc/dir1/fnoxdoc.pdf) (see page 6 for a US "heat map" of local NOx concentrations).

This [University of Washington report](http://faculty.washington.edu/jaegle/558/ozone_NOx.pdf) also contains a **global** NOx map, for both surface and 5km altitudes (page 10).

Comment: Thank you so much! Would it be OK if I leave the answer open so that other people can post other gasses, besides the ones mentioned?

Comment: @stackOverFlew, yes, absolutely.  I planned on coming back tomorrow and expanding on my answer as well.  I have some more sources that address your answer more directly than what I've already written.  But, certainly, feel free to wait until you get a more complete answer before accepting.

Answer (score 0):

The Vulcan Project at the University of Arizona provides GHG emissions by geography and source.

http://vulcan.project.asu.edu/research.php

Comment: Welcome to Sustainable Living! The link you've posted does look interesting, but just the link doesn't really answer the OPs question. Would it be possible to compile an answer?